# Использование результатов подзапросов в условии WHERE MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Есть запрос на выборку результат работы которого выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в запрос добавить условие по выбору значения special то получается ошибка неизвестная колонка special
Вот сам запрос с выборкой по условию

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
       ( SELECT price 
         FROM art_product_special ps 
         WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) 
         ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special 
FROM art_product_to_category p2c 
LEFT JOIN art_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN art_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN art_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '0' AND p2c.category_id = '18' AND special IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Как отфильтровать запрос по условию special ?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать используя HAVING
Вот пример

```
SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT price FROM art_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special FROM art_product_to_category p2c LEFT JOIN art_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN art_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN art_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '0' GROUP BY p.product_id HAVING special IS NOT NULL;
```